# Finding unique combinations irrespective of position

Tags: r, duplicates, combinations

I'm sure it's something simple, but I have a data frame

```
      df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3),
                       b = c(2, 3, 1),
                       c = c(3, 1, 4))
```

And I want a new data frame that contains the unique combinations of values in the rows, irrespective of which column they're in. So in the case above I'd want

```
    a b c
    1 2 3
    3 1 4
```

I've tried

```
    unique(df[c('a', 'b', 'c')])
```

but it sees (1, 2, 3) as unique from (2, 3, 1), which I don't want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like that

```
indx <- !duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))) # finds non - duplicates in sorted rows
df[indx, ] # selects only the non - duplicates according to that index
#   a b c
# 1 1 2 3
# 3 3 1 4
```

Answer (score 7):

If your data.frame is quite big, the speed may be a matter for you. You can find duplicated sets much faster with the following idea.

Let's imaginary assign each possible value in rows a prime number and count products for each row. For example, for given `df` we can accept `primenums = c(2,3,5,7)` and count products `c(30,30,70)`. Then duplicates in this products-vector correspond to duplicated sets in our data.frame. As multiplication is being computed much faster then any kinds of sorting, you can gain efficiency.
The code is following.

```
require("numbers")
primenums <- Primes(100)[1:4]
dfmult <- apply(as.matrix(df), 1, function(z) prod(primenums[z]) )
my_indx <- !duplicated(dfmult)
df[my_indx,]
```

Here we initialize vector `primenums` with the help of function `Primes` from package `numbers`, but you can do manually in other way.

Take a look at the example. Here I show comparison of efficiency.

```
require("numbers")

# generate all unique combinations 10 out of 20
allcomb <- t(combn(20,10))
# make sample of 1 million rows
set.seed(789)
df <- allcomb[sample(nrow(allcomb), 1e6, T),]
# lets sort matrix to show we have duplicates
df <- df[do.call(order, lapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) df[, i])), ]
head(df, 10)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#  [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#  [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#  [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#  [5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11
#  [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11
#  [7,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11
#  [8,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11
#  [9,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11
# [10,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11

# to be fair need to permutate numbers in rows before searching for identical sets
df <- t(apply(df, 1, function(z) z[sample(10,10)] ))
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- letters[1:10]
# how does it look like now?
head(df, 10)
#     a b c  d  e  f  g h  i j
# 1   2 3 7  9 10  1  4 8  5 6
# 2   4 2 6  3  8 10  9 1  5 7
# 3   4 2 6  8  5  1 10 7  3 9
# 4   6 8 5  4  2  1 10 9  7 3
# 5  11 2 7  6  8  1  9 4  5 3
# 6   9 6 3 11  4  2  8 7  5 1
# 7   5 2 3 11  1  8  6 9  7 4
# 8   3 9 7  1  2  5  4 8 11 6
# 9   6 2 8  3  4  1 11 5  9 7
# 10  4 6 3  9  7  2  1 5 11 8

# now lets shuffle rows to make df more plausible
df <- df[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)),]
```

Now when data.frame is ready we can test different algorithms.

```
system.time(indx <- !duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))) )
#   user  system elapsed 
# 119.75    0.06  120.03
# doesn't impress, frankly speaking

library(sets)
system.time(indx <- !duplicated(apply(df, 1, as.set)) )
#  user  system elapsed 
# 91.60    0.00   91.89
# better, but we want faster! =)

# now lets check out the method with prime numbers
primenums <- Primes(100)[1:20]
# [1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71
system.time({
  dfmult <- apply(as.matrix(df), 1, function(z) prod(primenums[z]) )
  my_indx <- !duplicated(dfmult) })
# user  system elapsed 
# 6.44    0.16    6.61
# not bad, isn't it? but lets compare results
identical(indx, my_indx)
# [1] TRUE

# So, if there is no difference, why wait more? ;)
```

There is one important assumption here - we use `as.matrix(df)`, but what if there are not only numeric variables in our `data.frame`? A more unificated solution will be as follows:

```
system.time({
  dfmult <- apply(
    apply(df, 2, function(colmn) as.integer(factor(colmn, 
                                                   levels = unique(c(as.matrix(df)))))),
    1, function(z) prod(primenums[z]) )
  my_indx <- !duplicated(dfmult) })
#  user  system elapsed 
# 27.48    0.34   27.84
# is distinctly slower but still much faster then previous methods
```

And what about if we have very much columns or very much different variables? In this case instead of `prod()` we can use `sum(log())` (which is being computed probably even faster for large numbers). Take a look at this.

```
pr <- Primes(5e7)
length(pr)   
# [1] 3001134
system.time(N <- sum(log(pr)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.12    0.00    0.13
N
# [1] 49993718
```

It's hard to imagine `df` with 3 mln columns, but here it's ok. This way allows us to carry `df` of any incredibly huge size with as many columns our RAM can hold.

Comment: That's a nice one, though not sure if you a bit cheating by doing `as.matrix(df)` here.

Comment: + 1 Very fast and I like the idea of using prime factorization but there are two limitations to this method: 1) If there are a large number of columns taking the product of primes will not work (e.g. `prod(Primes(200))` equals `prod(Primes(201))`) and  2) It won't work if the data frame contains a large number of distinct elements (because you need to generate a prime for each one, which can be cumbersome and also because the product won't be distinguishable by the computer as in the previous point)

Comment: To keep calm and not stay cheaters instead of `as.matrix` we can do `apply(df, 2, function(colmn) as.integer(factor(colmn, levels = unique(c(as.matrix(df))))))`. It will be slower but not very much, I'll give timings and update answer tomorrow, cause now am away from PC. And I agree, usage of prime numbers has limitations, but maybe you can try different r packages which allow to work with very huge numbers?

Comment: edited my answer developing the idea

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, the package `sets` provides a fast way of checking for set equality:

```
library(sets)
df.sets <- apply(df, 1, as.set)
#[[1]]
#{1, 2, 3}
#[[2]]
#{1, 2, 3}
#[[3]]
#{1, 3, 4}
df[!duplicated(df.sets),]
#  a b c
#1 1 2 3
#3 3 1 4
```