# Removing duplicate all-way-combinations while retaining all columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I need to remove duplicate combinations of two columns (feedID and feedID2) within groups (ID), while keeping a large number of other columns in the data set. All the rows with duplicates should be removed, whether it is A in column 2 and B in column 3 or vice versa.
Additionally, I would like to remove all rows where there is for example A in both columns, or where there is an NA in one of the columns.
I can not sort the data between columns, i.e. if A is in column nr 2, it should remain in column nr 2.

I know this might come across as a duplicate question, but none of the other answers seem to work with my data set, or asks for the same thing.
E.g.
 [Finding unique combinations irrespective of position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819921/finding-unique-combinations-irrespective-of-position?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Removing duplicate combinations in R (irrespective of order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-in-r-irrespective-of-order)

```
 test <- data.frame(ID= c("49V", "49V","49V", "49V", "49V", "52V", "52V", "52V"),
                      feedID = c("A1", "A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "B1", "D1",  "D2" ),
                    feedID2 = c("A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "NA", "D1", "D2",  "NA" ))

 desiredoutput <- data.frame(ID= c("49V", "52V", "52V"),
                      feedID = c("A1","B1", "D1" ),
                    feedID2 = c("G2", "D1", "D2" ))
```

the following code does not remove duplicates if in different columns

```
   test2 <- test [!duplicated(test[,c("ID","feedID", "feedID2")]),]
```

this code does not do anything at all but throws no error

```
  test2 <-  test%>% distinct(1,2,3) # where numbers refer to the columns
```

this code produces an error which for dimnames, not sure what that means. I do not get this with my test data, I am not sure why and cannot reproduce the error...

```
  indx <- !duplicated(t(apply(test, 1, sort))) # finds non - duplicates in sorted rows
   test[indx, ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `unique`?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the `ID` column.

Comment: Unique only keeps the selected columns, I need to keep them all (47!). @cephalopod

Comment: For each ID, I need to remove the duplicates. So if both ID 1 and 2 had the same combination of feedIDs, that would not count as a duplicate. Only within each ID can I remove duplicates. @AndrewBrēza

Comment: @Lisarv Ok, `nest` then use `unique` and `unnest` should do the job.....an example of `nest`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363535/how-to-create-a-list-of-list-and-then-perform-a-vectorised-function-over-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a base solution, using the `complete.cases` function, and also creating a sorted `feedID` column:

```
# remove any rows with NA values
test <- test[complete.cases(test[,c('ID', 'feedID','feedID2')]),]
#remove any rows with feedID == feedID2
test <- test[!(test$feedID == test$feedID2),]
# add new feedID3 column
test$feedID3 <- apply(test, 1, function(x) paste(sort(c(x[2], x[3])), collapse = '-'))
# remove any duplicates, and remove last column
test[!duplicated(test[,c('feedID3', 'ID')]), -4]


   ID feedID feedID2
2 49V     A1      G2
6 52V     B1      D1
7 52V     D1      D2
```

#### data

Note that we have converted `"NA"` to `NA`, and we have also set `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`

```
test <- data.frame(ID= c("49V", "49V","49V", "49V", "49V", "52V", "52V", "52V"),
                   feedID = c("A1", "A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "B1", "D1",  "D2" ),
                   feedID2 = c("A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", NA, "D1", "D2",  NA ),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Same comment as for Chi Pak below, it does not take group (ID) into account. My example should have been clearer, but if you replace the D and B to A and G you will see what I mean.

Comment: I think you edited the question just after I copied the code, now it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Guys, you are always so impatient. ;) Needed to try it properly on my own data first, and it works! Wish I could accept two answers as the other one worked just as fine in the end, but yeah...

Answer (score 1):

Your data again, but with `"NA"` changed to `NA` and `stringsAsFactors=F`

```
test <- data.frame(ID= c("49V", "49V","49V", "49V", "49V", "52V", "52V", "52V"),
                   feedID = c("A1", "A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "B1", "D1",  "D2" ),
                   feedID2 = c("A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", NA, "D1", "D2",  NA ),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)

 library(dplyr)
 test %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%             # Remove rows with NA
  rowwise() %>%                             # Perform next step by row
  mutate(dup=paste0(sort(c(feedID,feedID2)),collapse="")) %>%   # Sort and combine feedID and feedID2
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%                             # Remove rowwise grouping
  mutate(dup=duplicated(dup)) %>%           # Find duplicated feedID:feedID2 pairs
  filter(dup==F) %>%                        # Remove duplicated pairs
  filter(!(feedID==feedID2)) %>%            # Remove where feedID == feedID2
  select(-dup)                              # Remove dummy column


     ID feedID feedID2
1   49V     A1      G2
2   52V     B1      D1
3   52V     D1      D2
```

If you only want to look for `NA` in `feedID` & `feedID2`

replace `filter(complete.cases(.))` with `filter(!is.na(feedID) & !is.na(feedID2))`

Comment: It works, if I ignore the fact that there are NAs n other columns in the dataset as well... But there is. Can I just specify which column to look for complete.cases in?

Comment: I've added a solution to your comment at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: It does not take group into account though?

Comment: Your output does not suggest a logic for how you want to account for groups. Could you explain?

Comment: "duplicates within groups (ID)" means that duplicates should only be removed within each group (ID) and not across all groups. Thus, only duplicates within 49V, then only duplictaes within 52V etc...

Comment: Just added `group_by(ID)`

Comment: Thanks! This answer is just as good as the one I accepted, if anyone else would wonder!

Answer (score 0):

After changing "NA" to NA, and setting stringsAsFactors = F

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test <- data.frame(ID= c("49V", "49V","49V", "49V", "49V", "52V", "52V", "52V"),
                   feedID = c("A1", "A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "B1", "D1",  "D2" ),
                   feedID2 = c("A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", NA, "D1", "D2",  NA ),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)

desiredoutput <- data.frame(ID= c("49V", "52V", "52V"),
                            feedID = c("A1","B1", "D1" ),
                            feedID2 = c("G2", "D1", "D2" ),
                            stringsAsFactors = F)

test %>% 
  # Remove NAs and all rows where the IDs are equal
  filter(!is.na(feedID),                       
         !is.na(feedID2),                      
         feedID != feedID2) %>%                
  # Group rowwise and create a sorted pair of the two ID columns
  rowwise() %>%                                
  mutate(revCheck = str_c(str_sort(c(feedID, feedID2)), collapse = "")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # Find distinct ID pairs and keep all variables
  distinct(revCheck,
           .keep_all = T) %>% 
  # Find distinct rows for each ID pair. I kept these separate because I
  # think that's what you're asking for in your example, you want all
  # duplicates in feedID and all duplicates in feedID2 removed, not just
  # duplicate combinations of feedID and feedID2. See .keep_all in ?distinct
  distinct(feedID,
           .keep_all = T) %>% 
  distinct(feedID2,
           .keep_all = T) %>% 
  # Remove the sorted pair id
  select(-revCheck) %>% 
  # Return a dataframe
  as.data.frame(.)
```